# Не пойму до конца логики в работе с итераторами

Tags: python

Пример кода из учебника:

```
def mymapPad (*seqs, pad=None):
    seqs = [list(S) for S in seqs]
    res = []
    while any(seqs):
        res.append(tuple((S.pop(0) if  S else pad) for S in seqs)             
    return res 

S1, S2 = 'abc', 'xyz123'
print (mymapPad(S1,S2, pad=99))
```

В результате получаем:

```
[(‘a’, ‘x’), (‘b’, ‘y’), (‘c’, ‘z’), (99, ‘1’), (99, ‘2’), (99, ‘3’)]
```

Мне не понятен данный фрагмент кода:

```
while any(seqs):
    res.append(tuple((S.pop(0) if  S else pad) for S in seqs)
```

Пожалуйста объясните, что происходит в данном фрагменте и почему именно таким образом мы должны действовать? Почему здесь метод pop() Почему после else нет двоеточия и код работает? Почему за скобки необходимо опять написать ..)for S in seqs?

Comment: `res.append(tuple((S.pop(0) if  S else pad) for S in seqs)` У вас тут скобки не хватает

Comment: Для вставки кода есть специализированный инструмент, не стоит использовать цитаты для этой цели.

Answer (score 3):

1. 

```
while any(seqs):
```

Цикл идёт до тех пор, пока в списке seqs есть хотя бы один непустой список.

2.

```
res.append(tuple((S.pop(0) if  S else pad) for S in seqs))
```

На каждой итерации списка мы добавляем в `res` такой кортеж:

```
tuple((S.pop(0) if  S else pad) for S in seqs)
```

Чтобы его создать, используется генератор:

```
(S.pop(0) if S else pad) for S in seqs
```

Тут мы проходим по элементам списка `seqs` (который содержит списки символов). Если элемент (то есть список символов) не пуст, то в кортеж добавляется 0-й символ этого списка, а сам символ удаляется из списка. Если пуст, то обавляется `pad`.

```
S.pop(0) if S else pad
```

Такое выражение является так называемым тернарным оператором. В нём происходит буквально то, что в нём написано. Если выполняется `S`, то возвращается `S.pop(0)`. Иначе `pad`.

Этот код можно переписать так:

```
a = []
for S in seqs:
    if S:
        a.append(S.pop(0))
    else:
        a.append(pad)
res.append(tuple(a))
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Для уточнения хотел спросить а какая здесь задача у метода S.pop(0)? На сколько я знаю метод list.pop() в питоне удаляет элемент по указанному индексу и возвращает его. Не укладывается в голове...

Comment: @RinatGataullin, воспользуйтесь отладочной печатью и посмотрите, что происходит на каждой итерации https://ideone.com/x9eKhy